# Can't uninstall Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, uninstall

I'm using Elementary OS. I've installed Dropbox, now I can't uninstall it.

If I try to do it from the application centre it keeps on "applying changes". After about 2 hours, I abondoned this process.

Then I've tried both uninstalling and reinstalling it from the terminal. I got:

> Dropbox is the easiest way to share and store your files online. Want to learn more? Head to http://www.dropbox.com/
> Downloading Dropbox... 100%

Same as in app centre: it hangs. What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

Dropbox is a proprietary binary, so it should be relatively easy to track down all of the relevant files and `rm` them.

Run `sudo updatedb && locate dropbox` and then remove all of the files. 
`dropboxd` will probably be in `/usr/bin` (or `/bin/`, depending on your distro) and you will have some files in `$HOME/.dropbox`)...

Then log into to the web interface and unlink any linked devices and delete your account.

Comment: The dropbox binary files are found in `~/.dropbox-dist`. Probably this is not enough to eliminate dropbox entirely but you could try deleting this folder and try uninstalling it again.